# SoilGrids data R download WebDAV

Tags: raster, gdal, r, soilgrids

I am trying to download SoilGrids data with R following [this tutorial](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_R.md). I have tried it on Windows and macOS with GDAL version 2.4.4 and 3.1.2, respectively, but none of them worked. It threw me errors like `"ERROR 4: ...tileSG-007-062/tileSG-007-062_1-3.tif'not recognized as a supported file format"`, `"ERROR 4 .../cec/cec_0-5cm_mean.vrt' not recognized as a supported file format"` or sometimes ERROR 1.

It happened even when I used exactly the same codes shown in the tutorial. Would anyone help me with it?

Comment: can you post your code? I can reach the urls like this: https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/cec/cec_0-5cm_mean.vrt

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

`sg_url="/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/"`

to:

`sg_url="/vsicurl/https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/"`

I got the same error as you initially but doing the above fixed it.